# bnd wrap on jh.jar (JavaHelp) does not work

Tags: java, jar, osgi, javahelp, bnd

I am using bnd wrap, a tool that I have used many times before to convert a normal jar file into an OSGI bundle. I am having trouble with jh.jar from JavaHelp. I only get a warning saying, "1: Superfluous export-package instructions: [com, com.sun, com.sun.java.help, com.sun.java, javax]". I would expect a warning to not kill the process, but I do not see an OSGI bundle afterwards, my jh.jar does not change in file size and the manifest looks unchanged. Does anybody know what is going on? It should be easy enough for someone else to try and bnd wrap jh.jar themselves.

I am running this command:

```
bnd-wrap ./jh.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the correct jar was being created the entire time, it was just being renamed to jh.bar so it would not overwrite the original file.